# Mongo match in array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having a document of this structure

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5ee7ae75d0a23ba38c9b2aa6"),
"data": [{

        "startDateRange": ISODate("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "endDateRange": ISODate("2020-04-30T23:59:59.999Z")
    },
    {
        "startDateRange": ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "endDateRange": ISODate("2020-03-31T23:59:59.999Z")
    },
    {
        "startDateRange": ISODate("2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "endDateRange": ISODate("2020-05-31T23:59:59.999Z")
    }
 ] 
}
```

I need to do a query like **"startDateRange": ISODate("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")** is less than or equal to.
I am expecting output like this

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5ee7ae75d0a23ba38c9b2aa6"),
"data": [{

        "startDateRange": ISODate("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "endDateRange": ISODate("2020-04-30T23:59:59.999Z")
    },
    {
        "startDateRange": ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "endDateRange": ISODate("2020-03-31T23:59:59.999Z")
    }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: db.order.find({"data":{ $gte:ISODate("2020-05-10"), $lt:ISODate("2019-02-21") } }).pretty(); –

Comment: it will not work, sorry

Comment: (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)

Comment: it is returning all array

Comment: db.COLECIONNAME.find( { ID_or_ELEMENT: "63109" },
                 { DATE: { $elemMatch: { STARTDATE: 2020 } } } )